# Answer Deleted by Moderator on Closed Question?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, link-only-answers

I had a -20 reputation in my inbox today because a moderator came in and deleted an answer on a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991607/best-publish-subscribe-library-in-javascript/7996674#7996674

My answer was a short description of the pros/cons of one of the options requested in the question, PubSubJS:

> [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) publishes messages using setTimeout, which can make things difficult to debug.

While I realize it may not make sense to have any answers to a closed question, if the question is closed why not just let sleeping dogs lie? The answer I originally had there doesn't break any of the rules - it responds to the request for pros/cons of the frameworks. Sometime after I answered the question was closed - but why the delete? I can't even propose to have it undeleted because they're a moderator.

Answer (score 13):

Your answer was flagged 3 times for being a link-only answer, and the moderator simply responded to those flags. It was *one* sentence starting with the link.

You can still request it be undeleted, even when it was a diamond mod that deleted it, but I would at least expand the answer to contain a little more.. body.

Do note that the question is not stellar. You now have brought attention from various Meta users to it, and it *could* end up being deleted altogether because of that.

Comment: I usually avoid this. I'd rather just delete the whole question...

Comment: Actually it got three not an answer flags

Comment: Clicking undelete just gets me a message saying I can't - "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted." How would I request it be undeleted?

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: You flag it for mod attention, option 'other' and request it to be undeleted.

Comment: Well there's a procedure that needs some fixing.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: Why would that be? You can never undelete your own post you didn't delete yourself; that'd allow all sorts up trolls and spammers to keep resurrecting their spewage.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: Moderators are not ogres either; if you improved the post a bit, I'm sure a mod would be happy to undelete that for you.

Comment: When something is deleted and you disagree with it, and undelete is available: 1) The obvious procedure to initiate the undelete process is to click that link; if you can't do it, why even offer it? 2) If the actual process is the flag button, it doesn't make sense to tell the user it cannot be undeleted. It makes more sense for that undelete link to just initiate the flag process in that situation.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: I'm sure there is a feature request post here somewhere that asks for actions to be disabled if they are not available. The moderator flag route is the default route to take if you ever need something done or dealt with you don't have the power yourself to handle.

Comment: Sure, but neither of those avenues would solve this usability problem. Flag on most websites means "This is spam." The link is under the answer, not the delete action, so the chances a user realizes that's the way to express their disagreement with the deletion are low - the UI is just poorly presented here.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini But then again, most other sites have absolutely no way to actually bring content to the attention of people who can do something about it other than marking something spam, which isn't always true, even though some content certainly deserves to be removed. That's even worse UI. Flag != spam. That's silly. Those things are not synonyms.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: Note that you can no longer undelete the answer now; the whole question was deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW, I undeleted the answer before I deleted the question. ;)

Comment: @animuson: You are *such* a tease! :-P

Comment: @animuson Should that have restored the 20 karma? I still have it dinged from my rep, and the -20 deleted in my profile.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Well, no. The question is now deleted, which inherently deletes the answer, so you'd still lose the reputation from it anyways.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini and so does everyone else [lose reputation] who asked/answered...

Comment: @hayd Yes, unless they lost rep based on their votes, in which case they get it back.  All reputation gained/lost based on all questions/answers is reversed.

Comment: Well that's even worse - that Q&A, while not perfect, did have useful info on it - for example if I was looking for a quick pro/con on pub/sub frameworks in js, it served as a good enough starting point.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: Such questions do not really fit the format; take a look at http://www.slant.co/ for a platform that *is* suited to such posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed, but that makes those Q&As better for closing than deletion.